# Orthogonality Sin(nx)Sin(mx)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to prove that $$ \int_{0}^{\pi } \sin(n \, x) \, \sin(m \, x) \, \mathrm{d} x=0  $$ for m,n integers and $$ m\neq n$$
My try is:

```
$Assumptions = m ≠ n
$Assumptions = m ∈ Integers
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers
Integrate[Sin[m x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, π} ]
```

But no luck

Comment: Do you have a space (multiplication) between `m, n` and `x` ?

Comment: I didn't.... Now i am getting this  ((-1)^n n Sin[m π])/(m^2 - n^2)

Comment: Note that the assumption `m != n` is not needed to get a result of `0`.  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174011/how-to-get-a-universal-answer-using-integrate and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/how-to-code-around-known-mma-special-case-failures

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You overwrite `$Assumptions` several times, so it does not contain all the information that you meant to provide. Also `Simplify` can help where `Integrate` gave up the simplification. Try this:

```
$Assumptions = m != n && m ∈ Integers && n ∈ Integers
Simplify@Integrate[Sin[m x]*Sin[n x], {x, 0, π}]
```

Comment: Great, thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Also `$Assumptions = m \[Element] Integers && n \[Element] Integers` gives the same result `0` which is obviously wrong for the case `n==m` . Still (v12)  a Mathematica problem?

Comment: Uh, yes. Must be the thing about `Simplify` assuming some generacity of the symbols... =/

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Funny, I was making the same comment at the same time under the OP. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Really funny, but you made it with more helpful details...